# Calling jQuery on code behind with if condition

Tags: jquery

I want to call a jquery on my code behind page when the condition is true.

My jquery is mentioned below which includes an array and two functions i.e hideAllmessage and showMessage. By default all messages will be hidden and if any condition is met , success , error , info , warning message will be displayed. Its a plugin which I have searched and want to implement. My code is mentioned below:

JQUERY FUNCTION

```
var myMessages = ['info', 'warning', 'error', 'success']; // define the messages types         
function hideAllMessages() {
    var messagesHeights = new Array(); // this array will store height for each

    for (i = 0; i < myMessages.length; i++) {
        messagesHeights[i] = $('.' + myMessages[i]).outerHeight();
        $('.' + myMessages[i]).css('margin-top', -messagesHeights[i]); //move element outside viewport      
    }
}

function showMessage(type) {
    $('.' + type + '-trigger').click(function () {
        hideAllMessages();
        $('.' + type).animate({ marginTop: "0" }, 500);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    // Initially, hide them all
    hideAllMessages();

    // Show message
    for (var i = 0; i < myMessages.length; i++) {
        showMessage(myMessages[i]);
    }

    // When message is clicked, hide it
    $('.message').click(function () {
        $(this).animate({ marginTop: -$(this).outerHeight() }, 500);
    });
});
```

CODE BEHIND

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>showMessage('error')</Script>");
```

Comment: whats the question here?

Answer (score 0):

You can only register your javascript in the code behind as you did. You cannot call the created script from the code behind because it is executed **before** javascript. There are two only options for the moment.

1. to use nodejs on the server side
2. to use ajax request to do whatever you need when and after
   javascript has been loaded.

Comment: My question here is that..it aint showing any thing !! to check weather condition is true, i created a label with visibility hidden and it displayed.

Comment: > to call a jquery on my code behind page - this is your question, right? If you need to show/hide anything (messages in your case) you have two options: apply logic in javascript code and attach it to desired event OR make a ajax call to check whether condition is met and depending on result returned show/hide whatever. There is a third option actually - so called postback - that might seems as an interaction between code behind and javascript but it is too heavy and is not effective for that purpose.

Comment: i need some detailing...what logic i need to apply for javascript code ? its simple that I want to call a jquery function on my code behind if certain condition is met else not.

Comment: you do not mention any conditions but let's suppose you want to validate a username input. Then you'll have to attach validation to onblur event for instance and you'll have something like <input type="text" id="uname" onblur="checkit(this)" /> and a function checkit(el) { if(el.value.length === 0) { /*show your message*/} else { /*hide your message*/ } }. Hope you;ll get the idea

Comment: Thankyou for your reply. In my scenario, i've a textbox in which a user will input a complain number. on button click, complain # will be compared with my database and if any entry will be found then jquery function showMessage('error') must be called and it'll then hide automatically. so my code on button click will be somehow like 

SQL CODE
blah blah
if da.dt(Fill) == 1
showMessage('error')     and Message will be diplayed sliding from                       top and hide automatically

Comment: so you need either ajax or postback. I personally prefer the former. So on click make an ajax call. the page you call will make a check in DB and will return whatever result you need (i.e., 1=true;0=false). Upon the result you'll call your showMessage('error') or will hide error message and go on...

Comment: I am not familiar to Ajax call though. can u share some knowledge. Secondly, my ajax call will be like.. if ( result = 1 ) { ajax call} else { insert data }

Comment: This is to long topic to be able to cover it here, you could take a look in jquery ajax documentation at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/. In your case you'll need probably to ajax calls one to check and one to insert when ready.

Comment: ahaan !! what if i want to use a jquery alert box....do i have to call ajax on my code behind or is there any other approach for which i cant handle it? Like if ( dt.da(fill) == 1) { alertbox for jquery will appear} else it will not !! p.s ( currently i am using windows alertbox which comes handy in Page.Clientscript)

Comment: in the if clause you could put whatever code you need including query alert box. You might code its configuration in the code behind but it will be actually executed when it arrive at the client - that is what you are doing with Page.Clientscript.

Comment: if this is the case then why my code behind configuration is not working. I've used a ClientScript.Register in order to call my function which will actually display message. My function is on html page and working on jfiddle.Any idea ??

Comment: My function is on html page and working on jfiddle.Any idea ?? My code is if ( textbox1.Text.Length == 1) {ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>showMessage('error')</Script>"); } else {insert data}...Why this function is not working on code behind ? Any idea

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<input id="textbox1" onblur="test()" />
function test(){
 if ( $('#textbox1').val().length == 1) {  showMessage('error'); }
}
```

but you should dig more in the matter. It won't be enough to follow someone else's code

Comment: m a bit concerned 4 logic.ignored hideAllMessages() from $.document.ready,it bydefault showd the div which was hidden,den   Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Cl me", "hideAllMessages();");", true); on button clk n my div hid,means func is working ok bt when i did the same for showMessage(myMessages["error"]).it dint show anything whilst i remove my hideAllmessages stat. from being ignored. while calling showMessage func, am also intended to call any type of div which r declared in an array!!calling a function with an array type ? how can we call it? need to knw da syntax

Comment: you could get rid of  Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Cl me", "hideAllMessages();");", true); Decorate all message div with class having display:none and it should work. It is messy for me to combine javascript from code behind with javascript code loaded from external file or embedded into html page.